# Can the Window Controls (Max, Min, Close) and the Title be moved to the Bottom?

Tags: themes, metacity, window-buttons, emerald

I know I can move them to the left or the right, even on the middle, but I've never seen a window with it's controls and title on the bottom instead on the top.

Is it even possible to? Like if I could make a Emerald theme and put them there, or a Metacity theme and do the same?

If Emerald orMetacity can't do this, what about other Window Managers?

Comment: I've fiddled with Emerald themes before, and I don't think it would support it. Metacity, I'm not sure, since I've never even looked into what it can do.

Comment: Would it be possible with another Window Manager?

Comment: none that come to my mind. Hence why I voted up your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The 2 choices are top left or top right.