# How to make the window manager to show the X - [ ] not on left top corner but bottom left or bottom right corner?

Tags: 11.04, window-manager

Ubuntu 11.04, how can i change the Windows close/minimize/maximize buttons on top left corner to somewhere else like: bottom left corner, bottom right corner? If it's not possible, then I would like to put top right corner. Example as following window:

```
+---------------- + - [ ]--+
|                          |
|  Hello world             |
|     Ubuntu 11.04         |
|   Hero is here           |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

I have tried command lines from these questions:

- [How do I move the Window buttons from left to right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579/how-do-i-move-the-window-buttons-from-left-to-right)
- [Can the Window Controls (Max, Min, Close) and the Title be moved to the Bottom?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48827/can-the-window-controls-max-min-close-and-the-title-be-moved-to-the-bottom)

But none was working with Ubuntu 11.04, the only one worked was (Ubuntu Tweak), but in that case I do not have the terminal/command line to make my own custom script for future use.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04, those did not worked. Ubuntu Tweak only worked but no command lines i am finding yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your window decorator I am sure you can, in example, using emerald to create your own theme which will allow you to define where do you wish to place these controls.

Anyway, [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) will allow you to set the place on where these controls are displayed on your windows top corners, left or right, and will also allow you to re-arrange the buttons with your preferences.

Take a look at this screenshot:
[image]
*This options can be found under "Window Manager Settings" in Ubuntu Tweak*

I hope this help you.

Good luck!

Comment: This worked really thanks. But i want to do it with terminal to have the command lines. Possible to see the code which telling to send right or loeft?

Comment: You don't mention on your original question that you wish a command line solution, which would be useful in order to they don't mark your question as closed because of "exact duplicate", which in my humble point of view, is quite different than other questions, they are similar but your case is unique as you expect a command line solution. Just for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could move it to bottom but basically you could change it to right top corner

`gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string "menu:minimize,maximize,close"`

or you can do the same with gui

`gconf-editor /apps/metacity`

You could avoid the `menu` option as well.

Comment: I tried both example, but did not worked to move it at-least on right top corner, i am using Ubuntu 11.04.